# Are table names in MySQL case sensitive?

Tags: mysql, case-sensitive, mysql5

Are table names in MySQL case sensitive?

On my Windows development machine the code I have is able to query my tables which appear to be all lowercase. When I deploy to the test server in our datacenter the table names appear to start with an uppercase letter.

The servers we use are all on Ubuntu.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Answer (score 272, accepted):

In general:

**Database and table names are not case sensitive in Windows, and case sensitive in most varieties of Unix.**

> In MySQL, databases correspond to directories within the data
>   directory. Each table within a database corresponds to at least one
>   file within the database directory. Consequently, the case sensitivity of the
>   underlying operating system plays a part in the case sensitivity of
>   database and table names.

One can configure how tables names are stored on the disk using the system variable `lower_case_table_names` (in the **my.cnf** configuration file under [mysqld]).

Read the section: [10.2.2 Identifier Case Sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) for more information.

Comment: This totally burned me as my code was working great on my local windows environment, but throwing exceptions when moved into production on linux!! Thanks!

Comment: There is one caveat to this answer, which is not mentioned in the documentation: InnoDB does not use file or directory names for databases and tables, and therefore *its* objects are *always* case insensitive, even when run on a case sensitive system.  See this question for an example of what can go wrong because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23182969/innodb-complaining-about-foreign-key-name-in-use-when-restoring-database-after-d/23183479#23183479

Comment: this is not the whole story. see StephenLembert's answer as it is configurable

Comment: By default most mac computers use a case-insensitive file system. You can opt-in to have your file system be case-sensitive, though.

Answer (score 119):

Database and table names are not case sensitive in Windows, and case sensitive in most varieties of Unix or Linux.

To resolve the issue, set the lower_case_table_names to 1

> lower_case_table_names=1

This will make all your tables lowercase, no matter how you write them.

Comment: They are also not case sensitive on MacOS X, even though the underlying Unix is. This is presumably why autocomplete within MySQL on the Mac is case-sensitive for table or field names even though queries are not.

Comment: Yes, but there to put this statement? I guess it is on: /etc/mysql/my.cnf underneath [mysql]  group. But this is not enough, still something else needs to be done (besides of course restart mysql...

Comment: This only affects new tables. Existing tables have to be renamed to lowercase before changing this setting.

Comment: where to set "lower_case_table_names=1" ? Someone mentioned somewhere that it needs to be done in my.cnf under /etc/mysql but that fails server restart.

Comment: you may find [mysqld] in the file named "/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf". edit that file and add the line lower_case_table_names=1 under [mysqld].

Answer (score 35):

It depends upon `lower_case_table_names` system variable:

```
show variables where Variable_name='lower_case_table_names';
```

There are three possible values for this:

- ***`0`*** - lettercase specified in the `CREATE TABLE` or `CREATE DATABASE` statement. Name comparisons are case sensitive.
- ***`1`*** - Table names are stored in lowercase on disk and name comparisons are not case sensitive.
- ***`2`*** - lettercase specified in the `CREATE TABLE` or `CREATE DATABASE` statement, but MySQL converts them to lowercase on lookup.
  Name comparisons are not case sensitive.

[Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

Answer (score 20):

Table names in MySQL are file system entries, so they are case insensitive if the underlying file system is.

Comment: I don't think that's always true for InnoDB tables.

Comment: @SimonEast Will you please give a reason you think that?

Answer (score 18):

1. Locate the file at `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`
2. Edit the file by adding the following lines:

   ```
    [mysqld]

    lower_case_table_names=1
   ```
3. `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`
4. Run `mysqladmin -u root -p variables | grep table` to check that `lower_case_table_names` is `1` now

**You might need to recreate these tables to make it work.**

Comment: If you get an error `Different lower_case_table_names settings for server ('1') and data dictionary ('0').` recreate the database/tables.

Comment: Hello there, if you guys are on Ubuntu and can't start the mysql service after the 3rd step. Use this: https://github.com/igrmk/ubuntu-reinit-mysql

Answer (score 1):

Refer This [Doc][1]

Use **lower_case_table_names=0 on *Unix*** and **lower_case_table_names=2 on *Windows***.
[1]: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server X.X\my.ini -> Edit

Add the below line after **[mysqld]**

lower_case_table_names = 2