# How to personalize table names for ACL?

Tags: mysql, symfony, acl

In my database schemas, normally, I use a standardized naming system for all my tables. Symfony, and I guess, ACL itself, use a particular names for his tables in his schema.

This is the default name for the tables:

- acl_security_identities
- acl_classes
- acl_object_identities
- acl_object_identity_ancestors
- acl_entries

**Is there any way to change the names for those tables?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Unless you want to fork the security component of Symfony and hack it to your needs.
If so, this is a good place to start:
https://github.com/symfony/Security/tree/master/Acl/Resources/schema

Comment: Do you know if is case sensitive with the table names? .....using for example ACL_Group

Comment: Case sensitivity will depend on you DB servers configuration in most cases.

Comment: about case sensitive table names => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134006/are-table-names-in-mysql-case-sensitive

Answer (score 1):

**YES!**

There is a possibility to customize the table names!

http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/configuration/security.html

```
  acl:
    tables:
        class:                acl_classes
        entry:                acl_entries
        object_identity:      acl_object_identities
        object_identity_ancestors:  acl_object_identity_ancestors
        security_identity:    acl_security_identities
```