# Got SQLException table doesn't exist using quartz jdbcstore

Tags: java, mysql, quartz-scheduler

Iam implementing Quartz Scheduler using jdbcstore.I got exception like qrtz_TRIGGERS is not available.

```
2013-05-03 07:58:38,211 -  - DEBUG, [main], com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, Testing a Connection in response to an Exception:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'myData.qrtz_TRIGGERS' doesn't exist
```

But actually table is available in my database and the table name is qrtz_triggers.the table name is all are small letters. So How to resolve this issue and my quartz properties below

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = APP1_SCHEDULER
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 4
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = true

#specify the jobstore used
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false

#The datasource for the jobstore that is to be used
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS

#quartz table prefixes in the database
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = qrtz_
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = false

#The details of the datasource specified previously
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myData
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user = root
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password = root
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections = 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming your table to qrtz_TRIGGERS? It looks like this is what the scheduler is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In General:

**Database and table names are not case sensitive in Windows, and case sensitive in most varieties of Unix.So qrtz_TRIGGERS and qrtz_triggers is different in your case.**

Take a quick look: 
[Are table names in MySQL case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134006/are-table-names-in-mysql-case-sensitive)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you db is case sensitive, you should update your configuration file  my.cnf accordingly...

Below link for a help page For making your mysaql on linux machine case insensitive:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59407/how-to-make-mysql-table-name-case-insensitive-in-ubuntu