# InnoDB complaining about foreign key name in use when restoring database after dropping all tables

Tags: mysql, constraints, innodb

I'm trying to use `mysqldump` to copy data from one server to another.  The target server had a previous version of the same database installed, so all objects referenced already exist.  I checked the output from `mysqldump` and it includes appropriate statements to (1) disable foreign key checks during the recreation and (2) drop the old tables.  An edited excerpt looks like this:

```
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
...
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `bins`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `bins` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `site` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `capacity` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cost` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `sites_bins_idx` (`site`),
  CONSTRAINT `sites_bins` FOREIGN KEY (`site`) REFERENCES `sites` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=457 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

I understand the `/*!nnnnn ... */` syntax to be a conditional syntax that only executes if the server version is higher than the included number (which mine is, being 5.0), so all the included SET statements should be executing.

I ran the script file generated by running `mysql -p < dump.sql`, but received the following error:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 27: Can't create table './myschema/bins.frm' (errno: 121)
```

Running the query `show innodb status` gives the following additional information:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
140420 13:15:07 Error in foreign key constraint creation for table `myschema/bins`.
A foreign key constraint of name `myschema/sites_bins` already exists.
```

However, how can the constraint exist when the table(s) it refers to have been dropped?

```
mysql> show tables;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT    constraint_name,   table_name FROM    information_schema.table_constraints  WHERE    constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'    AND table_schema = DATABASE()  ORDER BY    constraint_name;
+--------------------------+------------------+
| constraint_name          | table_name       |
+--------------------------+------------------+
| clients_sites            | sites            |
| client_contacts          | contacts         |
| scheduledvisit_site      | scheduled_visits |
| sites_bins               | bins             |
| sites_visits             | site_visits      |
| sitevisit_sitevisitentry | site_visit_entry |
+--------------------------+------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I've even tried `drop database myschema`, but the constraints are still left behind even after this.

How have these constraints been left behind after their tables have been dropped?  And how do I get rid of them so I can recreate their respective tables?

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB's handling of object names is case insensitive.  MySQL's is dependent on the operating system's filename handling, which in my case was case *sensitive*.  A previous version of the database had been created with the names capitalised at the start, so while MySQL was aware of a database `myschema` which was empty and `MySchema` which was not, InnoDB considered the two to be the same.  Dropping the `MySchema` database allowed me to restore the dump from the remote system.