# Issue migrating from Adobe Coldfusion 10 to Lucee 4.5.1 - accessing structure

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I'm currently attempting to migrate my site from Adobe Coldfusion 10 to Lucee 4.5.1.

I'm getting the following error: `key [TITLE] doesn't exist`.

The code I was using was:

```
<cfset variables.title = ress.title.welcome>
```

The code that I need to fix the issue seems to be:

```
<cfset variables.title = ress["title.welcome"]>
```

I'm using JavaRB and loading a properties file (`onRequestStart()`) and setting it to the variable ress.

```
<cfset ress = utilObj.getResourceBundle()>
```

Is there an alternative other than going through my code to fix all the references? Is there a setting in the server to exhibit the old behavior?

**Update #1**

Properties files looks like this:

```
# @comment 
title.welcome=Content here
```

**Update #2**

This currently works on CF10 Developer on Windows 2008 R2 and CF10 on my shared host which is also Windows Server. I will also acknowledge that this is old code :)

JavaRB returns a structure from the content of the file:

```
var resourceBundle=structNew(); // structure to hold resource bundle
...
<cfreturn resourceBundle />
```

Partial CFC and method calls...

```
<cfcomponent name="utils" output="false">

    <cfset this.ress = "">

    <cffunction name="init">
        <cfscript>
            this.ress = loadResourceBundle();
        </cfscript>
        <cfreturn this>
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="loadResourceBundle" access="public" output="true">
        <!--- Get javaRB --->
        <cfinvoke component="#application.cfcPath#.javaRB" method="init" returnvariable="rb">
        </cfinvoke>
        <cfscript>
            rbFile = GetDirectoryFromPath(expandpath("/resources/")) & "mgs.properties";
        </cfscript>
        <cfreturn rb.getResourceBundle("#rbFile#")>
    </cffunction>
    ...
</cfcomponent>


<cfcomponent displayname="javaRB" output="no">
    <cffunction access="public" name="init" output="No">
        <cfscript>
            rB=createObject("java", "java.util.PropertyResourceBundle");
            fis=createObject("java", "java.io.FileInputStream"); 
            msgFormat=createObject("java", "java.text.MessageFormat");  
            locale=createObject("java","java.util.Locale");
        </cfscript>

        <cfreturn this>
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction access="public" name="getResourceBundle" output="No" returntype="struct" hint="reads and parses java resource bundle per locale">
        <cfargument name="rbFile" required="Yes" type="string" />
        <cfargument name="rbLocale" required="No" type="string" default="en_US" />
        <cfargument name="markDebug" required="No" type="boolean" default="false" />
        <cfscript>
            var isOk=false; // success flag
            var keys=""; // var to hold rb keys
            var resourceBundle=structNew(); // structure to hold resource bundle
            var thisKey="";
            var thisMSG="";
            var thisLang=listFirst(arguments.rbLocale,"_");
            var thisDir=GetDirectoryFromPath(arguments.rbFile);
            var thisFile=getFileFromPath(arguments.rbFile);
            var thisRBfile=thisDir & listFirst(thisFile,".") & "_"& arguments.rbLocale & "." & listLast(thisFile,".");
            if (NOT fileExists(thisRBfile)) //try just the language
                thisRBfile=thisDir & listFirst(thisFile,".") & "_"& thisLang & "." & listLast(thisFile,".");
            if (NOT fileExists(thisRBfile))// still nothing? strip thisRBfile back to base rb
                thisRBFile=arguments.rbFile;
            if (fileExists(thisRBFile)) { // final check, if this fails the file is not where it should be
                isOK=true;
                fis.init(thisRBFile);
                rB.init(fis);
                keys=rB.getKeys();
                while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
                    thisKEY=keys.nextElement();
                    thisMSG=rB.handleGetObject(thisKey);
                    if (arguments.markDebug)
                        resourceBundle["#thisKEY#"]="****"&thisMSG;
                    else
                        resourceBundle["#thisKEY#"]=thisMSG;
                    }
                fis.close();
                }
        </cfscript> 
        <cfif isOK>
            <cfreturn resourceBundle />
        <cfelse>
            <cfthrow message="#e.message#" detail="#e.detail#" type="#e.type#" />
        </cfif>
    </cffunction>
    ...
</cfcomponent>
```

**Update #3**

FWIW, I used the Eclipse IDE and did a find replace using a regex and replaced it with a value...

regex: `((ress\.){1}(([a-z\.])+))`

value: `ress["$3"]`

**Update #4**

So, using Lucee and MySQL, table names are case sensitive!?

Comment: What does the properties file entry look like?

Comment: @Leigh See update #1, that's what it looks like.

Comment: A plain vanilla [ResourceBundle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) would treat "title.welcome" as a single key, so I would not have expected it be handled as a nested structure, as you described, in any engine.  What kind of object is `utilObj` and what kind of object does `getResourceBundle()` return?

Comment: @Leigh See update #2, I've put relevant CFC/method calls...

Comment: Okay, so the issue is really that ACF treats structure key names containing a ".", like  `myStruct["title.welcome"]`, as nested structures, while Lucee does not.  Offhand, I do not know if there is a setting that changes the behavior. If not, you could always DIY. Create a function to split key names containing a "." and create the nested structures manually. Not the slickest option, but it would work.

Comment: @leigh table names are case-sensitive now, being on Linux/Lucee/MySQL?

Comment: Database table names? See [Are table names in MySQL case sensitive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134006/are-table-names-in-mysql-case-sensitive)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to Adobe ColdFusion, where syntactical mistakes are not punished immediately.

```
<cfset ress = { "title.welcome": "Content here" }>

<cfoutput>#ress.title.welcome#</cfoutput>
<!---

    >> outputs "Content here" in Adobe ColdFusion
    >> throws an exception in Lucee/Railo

--->
```

The behavior in Adobe ColdFusion is misleading and plain wrong. `"title.welcome"` is a key that is supposed to be put in the struct `ress`. Instead the key is split into two structs with the keys `"title"` and `"welcome"`, linked to each other and then put into the struct `ress`.

Your only chance to fix this issues is by adapting your `getResourceBundle` function. Here you need to refactor the lines with `resourceBundle["#thisKEY#"]` so that `thisKEY` creates a struct chain.

Comment: thanks, I'll have a look at this. Currently on a shared Windows Server / SQL Server host and contemplating migrating to Linux / Lucee / MySQL... I keep meeting these sorts of things on the way :)

Comment: Agreed. It only "works" by exploiting ACF's strange handling of structure key names containing a period. As I said above, I would not have expected it to work that way - in any engine.