# Issues with returning a dates after 2014

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hi so I'm trying to learn sql and am working on a small exercise. I want to return all the ids from a table that have a date after 2014.
Heres what I have:

```
     CREATE TABLE Pick_Up(
     eid INT, 
     pid INT,
     cid int,
     datetime DATETIME, 
     );
INSERT INTO Pick_Up (eid, pid,  datetime) 
VALUES (3, 7,'2015/4/23 16:35:05'),
       (4, 6,'2016/3/20/ 9:05:45');
SELECT P.pid
FROM pick_up P
WHERE year(p.datetime)> '2014';
```

And I thought it would return both tuples but when I run it i get nothing.  IF anyone could help by telling me what I can do to have it return both values that would be amazingly awesome!

Comment: The sample data you posted contains error in datetime data. Secondly, I believe year() function returns integer result so you should get rid of quotes around 2014 in the `where` condition.

Comment: Your query works for me once I change `p.datetime` to `P.datetime`. Otherwise I get an error.

Comment: @Barmar What? You have a case sensitive implementation of MySQL ???

Comment: `> '2014-12-31 23:59:59'` will be faster

Comment: @Strawberry http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134006/are-table-names-in-mysql-case-sensitive

Answer (score 0):

Only issue is syntax error,there is an extra comma,

```
SELECT P.pid FROM pick_up P WHERE year(p.datetime)> 2014;
```

Secondly year is numeric not string.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P.pid
FROM pick_up P
WHERE year(p.datetime)> 2014   [ year(p.datetime) may result in integer ]
```

or try something like this

```
SELECT P.pid
FROM pick_up P
WHERE datepart(yy,p.datetime)> 2014
```