# Why does phpmyadmin act different in uppercase query?

Tags: phpmyadmin

When using phpMyAdmin Ver. 4.0.10deb1, there is a table with a column named 'ID', which is a primary key. When I run the query "SELECT id FROM `table`" I get the error;

```
 This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.
```

But if I run "SELECT ID FROM `table`" it works fine. I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6134059/6346805) answer about PHPMyAdmin:

> Database and table names are not case sensitive in Windows, and case sensitive in most varieties of Unix.

So this should be the explanation for the error (assuming that phpMyAdmin Ver. 4.0.10deb1 is a non-Windows version)

Comment: Well the strange thing is the 2 queries produce identical results when done through command line so mysql treats upper and lower case the same it seems. BTW, these are MyISAM tables. So this is something phpMyAdmin is doing.