# Hibernate, works on Windows but not on Linux. It duplicates tables and mess around with some tables's name

Tags: javascript, java, linux, hibernate, ubuntu

I'm developing an enterprise management system using: JS, Java 8.91, Tomcat 8.5.4 and MySQL 5.7.

The system has many databases:

- Main Database that stores user's information(login, password, email and user's database name).
- User's Database, stores user's company information. When an user signs up, Hibernate creates a new DB for the new User.

It works perfectly on Windows but when I test it on UbuntuServer 16.04 64x, some bugs/issues happens, Hibernate:

- Duplicates almost every table from MainDB(example: it duplicates table "users". creates a new table "Users").
- When hibernate creates User's DB, it mess with tables name(example: hibernate should create a table named "address", but it creates a table named "Address" instead).

Honestly I don't know what's happening, I never saw this before and I don't know how to solve it. Every help/tip will be appreciated.

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: which is the database collation on the operative systems?

Comment: @ShaigKhaligli, thanks for the links. This is my first question at StackOverFlow.

Comment: Do you use names for your tables? For example, @Table(name="users")  
@Entity public class Users { ... }. Database and table names are not case sensitive in Windows, and case sensitive in most varieties of Unix (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134006/are-table-names-in-mysql-case-sensitive)

Comment: @Alejandra database collection is: utf8_general_ci

Comment: Both windows and Ubuntu using the same versions of MySQL?

Comment: @Naros, yes. MySQL version is the same.

Comment: @Justas, sorry for keeping you waiting. Yes but not at all classes... thats why hibernate duplicates table names. Thanks for that link, Justas.

Solution(as super user):
- cd /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d
- nano mysqld.cnf
- under [mysqld], add this line: lower_case_table_names = 1

Comment: Thanks for the support, guys. In the future, I'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference: [Are table names in MySQL case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134006/are-table-names-in-mysql-case-sensitive)

### Solution 1

- sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
- Under [mysqld], add this line: lower_case_table_names = 1
- sudo service mysql restart

### Solution 2

- Make sure you named all classes using @Table. Example: @Table(name="your_table_name")