# MySQL error 1215 cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

sorry i know there are loads about this but I don't understand them!

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
CustomerID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
LastName VARCHAR(50),
FirstName VARCHAR(50),
Address VARCHAR(255),
City VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID)
);

CREATE TABLE Film (
FilmID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
FilmName VARCHAR(100),
FilmRelease DATE,
FilmDirector VARCHAR(100),
RentalID int unsigned,
PRIMARY KEY (FilmID),
FOREIGN KEY (RentalID)
    REFERENCES rental (RentalID)
);

CREATE TABLE Rental (
RentalID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Price VARCHAR(25),
DateIn DATETIME,
DateOut DATETIME,
PRIMARY KEY (RentalID),
);
```

And yes my indenations may be off because of the way I copied and pasted it.

The error is the FOREIGN KEY RENTALID, it works if I use the foreign key as CustomerID from Customer

Comment: Just wondering: is this exactly the script you tried? Because here you would refer to rental table before having created it

Comment: Table name starts with capital letter. `FOREIGN KEY (RentalID)
    REFERENCES Rental (RentalID)`

Comment: `REFERENCES rental (RentalID)`  <---- try capitalizing rental to match the name of the table.  Also, does Rental exist when you try to add the FK to Film?

Comment: As Insac said, the Rental table must be created before Film table

Comment: I just wonder about any system in which a rental is the master to a film.  Seems a bit backwards.

Comment: @Insac yep thanks, rookie mistake

Comment: @Sefran2 I too thought it was the capital letter of my table, however when I run the script it creates all my tables with lowercase, despite me typing them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested the script on [RexTester](http://rextester.com/CRM56567) and indeed there were two issues:

- the foreign key on Film table was referring the Rental table before it was created
- in the Rental table there was a ","  after the definition of the primary key

Here is the final script (the initial drop are there just to allow for easy "drop and create" testing)

```
 drop TABLE if exists  Film ;
 drop TABLE if exists  Customer;
 drop TABLE if exists  Rental ;

 CREATE TABLE  Customer (
   CustomerID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   LastName VARCHAR(50),
   FirstName VARCHAR(50),
   Address VARCHAR(255),
   City VARCHAR(50),
 PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID)
 );



 CREATE TABLE  Rental (
   RentalID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   Price VARCHAR(25),
   DateIn DATETIME,
   DateOut DATETIME,
   PRIMARY KEY (RentalID)
 );


 CREATE TABLE  Film (
   FilmID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   FilmName VARCHAR(100),
   FilmRelease DATE,
   FilmDirector VARCHAR(100),
   RentalID int unsigned,

   PRIMARY KEY (FilmID), 

   FOREIGN KEY (RentalID) REFERENCES  Rental (RentalID)
 );
```

Comment: [Using my create table functions, I create 'Customers' and 'Films' but on the right you can see that the tables are created in lowercase][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwU2l.png

Comment: I think that is another question,  probably related to this one..  http://stackoverflow.com/q/6134006/5077154