# mySQL Uppercase Table Name

Tags: mysql

I have a database with tables already in the database. There is a table called Character that I am trying to access to add an additional column. However any command that I use with the table Character gives me the following error:

```
    mysql> SHOW FIELDS FROM Character;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Character' at line 1
```

I've tried the following commands:

```
mysql> SHOW FIELDS FROM "Character";
mysql> SHOW FIELDS FROM 'Character';
mysql> SHOW FIELDS FROM Character;
```

All three give me the same error. I have already selected the appropriate database that contains the Character table using the command "USE dbname;"

Comment: did yo try `SHOW TABLES` ? Or maybe you need `SHOW COLUMNS FROM mydb.\`Character\`;` OR `SHOW COLUMNS FROM \`Character\`;`

Comment: Ah. I was typing 'Character' instead of the one with ` `. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Character` is a reserved word therefore you should use backticks:

```
SHOW FIELDS FROM `Character`;
```

See it here [9.3 Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html)

Also, about the "Uppercase" (or not), read this answer [Are table names in MySQL case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6134059/460557)

On this image I'm using [MySql Workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)

[image]