# ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'aldobowi.section' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

MySQL-Table does not exist. Please, can anyone help?

```
mysql> show tables;
+--------------------+
| Tables_in_aldobowi |
+--------------------+
| Section            |
| course             |
| student            |
+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from section;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'aldobowi.section' doesn't exist
```

Comment: Depending on your operating system, `Section` may not be the same as `section`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are table names in MySQL case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134006/are-table-names-in-mysql-case-sensitive)

Answer (score 1):

The table names can be case sensitive. You are using `section` instead of `Section`. Most varieties of UNIX or LINUX systems are case sensitive.

Comment: Thank you very much its case sensitive.mysql> select * from Section;
+--------------------+--------------+------
| SectionIndentifier | CourseNumber | Year | Instructor |

|                 85 | MATH2410     |   98 | King       |
|                 92 | CS1310       |   98 | Andreson   |
|                102 | CS3320       |   99 | Knuth      |
|                112 | MATH2410     |   99 | Chang      |
|                119 | CS1310       |   99 | Andreson   |
|               1135 | CS3380       |   99 | Stone      |
+--------------------+--------------+------+------------+