# How to tell Springboot to use existing table in mysql rather than creating a new one

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to do an application with Springboot, that uses Mysql and Angular.  If I run the spring  application, it is creating a new table in mysql, and inserting values into it. Even though i wrote the table name in Uppercase as  "**T_EMPLEAVE"**, springboot is creating a new table in lowercase as "**t_empleave**" .Moreover, I have created the table with Uppercase in Mysql. But, my application is not using it. How to tell Spring boot to use the existing table instead of creating new table.

Following is my application.properties file.

```
spring.datasource.username=**
spring.datasource.password=***
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T_EMPLEAVE")
```

Comment: Depends on OS see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134006/are-table-names-in-mysql-case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your properties file or update the line if it already exists :

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Comment: I tried that. Still it is creating a new table with lowercase name.