# MySQL Error Code: 1054 when try "on" and " inner join"

Tags: mysql

i have problem with func "on".
this is the Query :

> Retrieving the names of dog lovers who have performed at least 3 babysitters in apartment type houses

```
CREATE TABLE DogLover (
DogLoverID INT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(50),
DailyWage INT,
phone INT,
city VARCHAR(50));

CREATE TABLE House (
HouseID INT PRIMARY KEY,
HouseType VARCHAR(50),
no_of_dogs INT, 
max_cancel_notice INT);

CREATE TABLE DogLoverShift (
DogLoverID INT,
HouseID INT PRIMARY KEY,
StartDate DATE,
EndDate DATE,
FOREIGN KEY (DogLoverID) REFERENCES DogLover(DogLoverID),
FOREIGN KEY (HouseID) REFERENCES House(HouseID));
```

the query that i try is :

```
SELECT *
FROM DogLoverShift inner join DogLover AS newTable
ON doglover.DogLoverID = doglovershift.DogLoverID
```

the error :

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'doglover.DogLoverID' in 'on clause'

***EDIT :***
after i see all the good help here, i change the query :

```
SELECT *
FROM DogLoverShift inner join DogLover inner join House AS newTable ON newtable.DogLoverID=DogLoverShift.DogLoverID AND newtable.HouseID=house.HouseID;
```

and the error :

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'newTable.DogLoverID' in 'on clause'

***EDIT 2:***
(hope the last edit .. )
now i use this code ( thansk to 'Arulkumar' !)

```
SELECT * 
FROM DogLoverShift AS DLS 
INNER JOIN DogLover AS DG ON DG.DogLoverID = DLS.DogLoverID
INNER JOIN House AS HS ON HS.HouseID = DLS.HouseID
```

now how i check : "performed at least 3 babysitters in apartment type houses"?
i know i need to group by, and make WHERE , but i dont know how :-(

Comment: most probably your server is a *NIX server and thus mysql is case sensitive (check the table names in the on clause). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134006/are-table-names-in-mysql-case-sensitive) for reference

Comment: You're  using pascal case in the create statement but all lower case in your `on` statement

Comment: You aliased the table to newTable. So use newTable.DogLoverID

Comment: @LelioFaieta , whit sensitive you mean the Caps Look lettrs ?

Comment: You alias your `DogLover` table as `newTable`,  so of course `doglover.DogLoverID` will fail.

Comment: thanks you all, now its work !!

Answer (score 0):

Your current syntax is off, because as soon as you aliased the `DogLover` table as `newTable`, you lost the ability to refer to `DogLover` again in the `ON` clause.  But, your current query is very far off from what you need, so here is one correct way to approach your query:

```
SELECT
    dl.name
FROM DogLover dl
INNER JOIN DogLoverShift dls
    ON dl.DogLoverID = dls.DogLoverID
INNER JOIN House h
    ON dls.HouseID = h.HouseID
GROUP BY
    dl.name
HAVING
    SUM(h.HouseType = 'Apartment') >= 3;
```

Comment: i know i fat away from the good syntax, i try to understand what i do here ..
anyway, i copy your code, and return res : 0..

Comment: @idan Without seeing your exact data, everyone who answers here would be guessing to some degree.  Can you tell us if the `HouseType` you want to match is actually `'houses'`?  Or, is it some other value (e.g. `house`, in the singular) ?

Comment: ok.. is google translate problem when i translate the question...  sorry
houses = Apartment ( in HouseType )

Comment: Please retry my query using `Apartment` as the house type you want to match.

Comment: ok, get 0 row's now.
but i will double check the database i have, i sure i have data for get some res

Comment: Consider adding a demo to your question using a site like [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk).

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with the table name `newTable`. You can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM DogLoverShift 
inner join DogLover AS newTable ON newTable.DogLoverID = DogLoverShift.DogLoverID
```

or directly with the table name

```
SELECT *
FROM DogLoverShift 
inner join DogLover ON DogLover.DogLoverID = DogLoverShift.DogLoverID
```

As per your comments, to join three tables, use the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DogLoverShift AS DLS 
INNER JOIN DogLover AS DG ON DG.DogLoverID = DLS.DogLoverID
INNER JOIN House AS HS ON HS.HouseID = DLS.HouseID
```

Comment: if i need to do inned join to 3 tables "DogLover,House,DogLoverShift"
what the syntax for this ?
i try like this and get the same error (1054) : SELECT *
FROM DogLoverShift inner join DogLover inner join House AS newTable ON newtable.DogLoverID=DogLoverShift.DogLoverID AND newtable.HouseID=house.HouseID

Comment: @idan Also instead of `SELECT *`, mention the required column names such as `SELECT DLS.DogLoverID, DG.HouseID, ....`

Comment: thanks you alot !
but, when i copy the code, same error : Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'DG.HouseID' in 'on clause'

Comment: but i want (for now, to know what my table show me) to see all the rows and coloms from the inner join, later when this table be done, i use the WHERE command and redo to SELECT*

Comment: @idan There is a typo, instead of `DG.HouseID` use `DLS.HouseID`

Comment: @idan You're Welcome. I'm glad I was able to help!