# When mounting /var/lib/mysql on Docker volume camel cased tables doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

I have mounted `mariadb/server:10.3` with `/var/lib/mysql` volume. I had issue while trying to perform query from backend which said that `Table <table name> doesn't exist in engine`.

I did perform `mysqlcheck` inside container and turned out that out of 20 tables two of them `doesn't exist in engine` - and both of them are CamelCased. All the others are snake_cased. Don't ask me why is that.

First thing I'm gonna do is to rename them, but that's actually quite strange given that it works perfectly everywhere else. Any potential solutions aside from renaming or just explanation why it that? Is that Docker's fault or db's?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are table names in MySQL case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134006/are-table-names-in-mysql-case-sensitive). Also in order to preserve table names you have to quote them using backticks `

Comment: Partly, because MacOs, as far as I know, is Unix so it shouldn't be a thing. But turns out it is

Comment: You didn't read all answers thoroughly. I'm not talking about the filesystem differences since there aren't any, like you said, both are Unixes.