# How to get table name in which case

Tags: mysql

I need a SQL query to check table name in which case.(upper/lower)
For example I have table name 'USER' so that query should return UPPERCASE or in the case of table name 'user' it should return lower case.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/q/6134006/3008984

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are table names in MySQL case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134006/are-table-names-in-mysql-case-sensitive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below query to get whether the tables were created as upper/lower case.

```
SELECT 
    TABLE_NAME,
    CASE TABLE_NAME REGEXP BINARY '[a-z]'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'lower'
        ELSE 'upper'
    END AS case_status
FROM
    information_schema.TABLES
WHERE
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'table_name';
```