# Presto show tables shows a nonexistent table due to case sensitivity with mysqldb

Tags: mysql, presto, trino

For the purposes of this question, I'm talking about `prestosql.io` or `Trino` after the rebranding.

I have a table (details redacted) here:

```
presto> SHOW TABLES FROM a.b;
     Table
----------------
 foo
...

presto> DESCRIBE a.b.foo;
Query <id> failed: line 1:1: Table 'a.b.foo' does not exist
DESCRIBE a.b.foo
```

and it lives inside of a mysql db. I have a presto catalog `a` that has a mysqldb connector to query its data from presto.

Strangely, it says `foo` even though my connection to `mysql` tells me it's `Foo` (f capitalized):

```
mysql> describe b.Foo;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
...

mysql> describe b.foo;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'b.foo' doesn't exist
```

And when I try to DESCRIBE this table in presto, it fails:

```
presto> DESCRIBE a.b.Foo;
Query <id> failed: line 1:1: Table 'a.b.foo' does not exist
DESCRIBE a.b.Foo
```

Upon inspection, notice how it says "Table **'a.b.foo'** does not exist", not **'a.b.Foo'**. Seeing how [mysql is case sensitive in most unices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134006/are-table-names-in-mysql-case-sensitive), it seems to me that the connector is passing in an invalid table name from Presto and there's no way for me to access the actual table.

If my hypothesis is right, how can I fix this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to handle non-lowercase table names in MySQL you currently need to set the `case-insensitive-name-matching=true` catalog property.

The more proper support for mixed-case table and column names will be provided in https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues/17 .