# MySQL tablename - lower or uppercase

Tags: mysql

In AWS, I only can set lower_case_table_names 0 or 1.

Currently my tablename is "myinvoices" in the MySQL server (on Linux).

However, I want to access it as
select * from MyInvoices (from any OS client)

I want mixed case as it looks clearer on my client code as some table names are long (not my choice).

from my query... however, both lower_case_table_names=0 or 1 will give an error.
Reading the   [Are table names in MySQL case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134006/are-table-names-in-mysql-case-sensitive), it seems that setting to 1 should make the database server ignore upper or lower case, but it doesn't work.

Please advise if this is possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Is your database server  running on RDS or an EC2 instance that you configured from scratch?

Comment: @matigo it's running on RDS. apologies, I didn't state that earlier.