# Spring Boot java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'mydb.table_name' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, linux, spring-boot

The table exists, I use SpringBoot, hibernate to create the tables, mysql for the database... I connect succesfully to the database in the app. The tables are created and all that.
My application ran perfectly on Windows. But now I have Linux and it just gives me this error what is it? There is no error in the code this I know for sure its something from the database but I dont know what...any thoughts?

Comment: MySQL on Windows is case insensitive, but Linux is case sensitive. Is name of table in correct case?

Comment: If the problem turns out to be the case of the table names (Credits to @Boris). see here. There is a way to make MySql behave ok on both Windows and Linux if this is the case.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134006/are-table-names-in-mysql-case-sensitive

Comment: yes I think its the case, but how do I modify it?

Comment: the "my.cnf" file is empty. I write "lower_case_table_names=0" in it and then after I run mysql it says it doesnt recognise the variable. what do I need to write ib my.cnf because I really dont understand

Comment: It is better to change mysql case sensitivity setting. make it case insensitive.

Comment: I solved it, thank you. I didnt add the line "[mysqld]" in the my.conf file 
[mysqld]
lower_case_table_names = 1
now it works. thank everyone

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are table names in MySQL case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134006/are-table-names-in-mysql-case-sensitive)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to copy answer from comments.
The problem is that Windows is case insensitive but Linux is case sensitive.

MySQL configuration:

```
[mysqld]
lower_case_table_names=1
```

Link that @Nandostyle referenced with same issue: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134006/are-table-names-in-mysql-case-sensitive)